# I am scripting buttons for a tycoon game in Roblox, but I keep getting the error messages "expected identifier when parsing variable name got '='"

Tags: scripting, roblox

I am having multiple error messages about my scripts. I am new to scripting, so maybe I am just being dumb, but I don't see what is causing the issues. The first issue is with the =. it says, "expected identifier when parsing variable name got '='". The second issue is with the player part. It says, "unknown global 'player'". Anyone know how to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Here is the script that has the issue:
(The issues are where I have put asterisks)

```
                                   v.Button.Touched:connect(function(hit)
                local *=*game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
                if *player* then
                    if values.OwnerValue.Value == *player* then
                        if v.Button.CanCollide == true then
                            if *player*
                        end
                    end
                    
                end
            end)
        end
    end)
end
```

end

I thought that the script was going to make the buttons for my game work. (I took the scripts from a YouTube tutorial), but it gave me these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the entire script's context so I can actually figure out what's going on. It looks like an issue with the "Player" Variable.

Also

```
local *=*game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
```

You must have a name for your variable, You can't just do

```
local = (item)
```

gotta use something like this:

```
local a = (item)
```

it looks like it also cuts off at the end, we need what's beyond that